# Oracle 11g Rel 2 installation on windows 2008 Server

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

I am SQLServer guy but due to some reason I need to create a VM of windows 2008 R2 standard server and want to install Oracle 11g R2 64bit. I have installed a loop back adapter and gave IP : 10.10.10.10
Subnet : 255.255.0.0

now do I need to add something in host file?

I tried installing but I never got working Enterprise Manager. It does show up when I type this   `https://myhostname:1158/em` with login, password and role box I tried

User     :  SYS
Password :  mysyspassword
Role     :  SYSDBA

Then I get "Inernal error occured" ..

Why Enterprise manager never works like expected or is there a bug in the 11.2.0.0.1 release?

Hope someone here would be able to tell me what steps do i need to make it work.

Comment: can you show us the install log? I would not assume that just because you get an error when starting Enterprise manager that there is a bug in the software.

Comment: where do i need to look for the log related to Enterprise Manager?

Comment: look in C:\app\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\YourServerName.YourDomain_YourDatabaseName\sysman\log for emagent.log and emagent.trc

Comment: kevinsky i think i reached near to the problem. its the timezone issue. how to change the timezone

Comment: You have to help me before I can help you. What does the log say?  Quote the exact error message.

Comment: no such log files exist anyway

Comment: Error connecting to https://EasyServer:3938/emd/main. Returning status code 1
2014-01-10 22:04:30,902 Thread-2512 ERROR main: nmectl.c: nmectl_validateTZRegion, agentTZoffset =240,and testTZoffset for -04:00:-240 do not match